# iaik pkcs#11 wrapper and java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror, pkcs#11, iaik-jce

I am trying to run a simple sample code from iaik pkcs#11 wrapper (version 1.3, the latest atm) but get `NoSuchMethodError` on `pkcs11Module.initialize` call.

```
Module pkcs11Module = Module.getInstance("siecap11");
pkcs11Module.initialize(null); 
Slot[] slots = pkcs11Module.getSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.TOKEN_PRESENT);
for (Slot s: slots) {
    System.out.println(s.getSlotID());
}
pkcs11Module.finalize(null);
```

Exception stack trace is as following

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Initialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V
at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module.initialize(Module.java:308)
at test.pkcs11.Pkcs11Service.listSlotsWithTokens(Pkcs11Service.java:98)
at test.pkcs11.TestPkcs11Service.testListSlots(TestPkcs11Service.java:35)
```

A similar code works fine on Linux, so i am guessing there is something wrong with pkcs11wrapper.dll.

`pkcs11wrapper.dll` and `siecap11.dll` are in `c\windows\system32` directory and both are 32bit modules.

I have tried a different pkcs#11 provider, debug and release versions of pkcs11wrapper but the result was the same.

The debug version of the pkcs11wrapper.dll generates the following output:

```
11/26/13 21:30:50   CALL: entering (in Java_iaik_pkcs_pkcs11_wrapper_PKCS11Implementation_initializeLibrary)
11/26/13 21:30:50   CALL: exiting  (in Java_iaik_pkcs_pkcs11_wrapper_PKCS11Implementation_initializeLibrary)
11/26/13 21:30:50   CALL: entering (in Java_iaik_pkcs_pkcs11_wrapper_PKCS11Implementation_connect)
11/26/13 21:30:50   INFO: connect to PKCS#11 module: siecap11 ...  (in Java_iaik_pkcs_pkcs11_wrapper_PKCS11Implementation_connect)
11/26/13 21:30:50   CALL: exiting  (in Java_iaik_pkcs_pkcs11_wrapper_PKCS11Implementation_connect)
```

The utility applications that came with the smart cards work fine, so is opensc pkcs11-tool.

EDIT:

Using version 1.2.17 of pkcs11 wrapper library and its accompanying dll, the code above works without a problem. But the original question remains unresolved.

EDIT2:

Following code, suggested by SubOptimal generates the following output.

```
@Test
public void testFindLibrary() {
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("path.separator");
    String libraryPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
    for (String dir : libraryPath.split(lineSeparator)) {
        File f = new File(dir + "/" + "pkcs11wrapper.dll"); 
        if (f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("found in: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
found in: C:\Windows\system32\pkcs11wrapper.dll
found in: C:\Windows\system32\pkcs11wrapper.dll
found in: C:\Windows\system32\pkcs11wrapper.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving to a new computer the problem vanished. There was possibly another version of DLL somewhere in the java library / system path.

Answer (score 5):

the exception

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Initialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V
```

states that a method with the signature `void C_Initialize(Object o, boolean b)` should be called and doesn't exist. And you're right with your guess `so i am guessing there is something wrong with pkcs11wrapper.dll.` Based on the Javadoc this method signature has been changed
[PKCS#11 Wrapper version 1.3](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11.html#C_Initialize%28java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) and [PKCS#11 Wrapper version 1.2.15](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/1.2.15/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11.html#C_Initialize%28java.lang.Object%29) (could not find one for 1.2.17).

So your DDL `pkcs11wrapper.dll` is for an older version. You can check the version in the file properties menu under Windows.

**edit**
Seems the dll from version 1.2.17 is somewhere in the java.library.path. I did following tests with the GetInfo.java from iaikPkcs11Wrapper archive.

```
dll      jar      result
1.2.17   1.2.17   work successful
1.2.17   1.3      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation.C_Initialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V
1.3      1.3      work successful
1.3      1.2.17   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation.C_Initialize(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

The combination dll-1.2.17 and jar-1.3 produces your exception.

You could run following code to find the dll in an unexpected location

```
import java.io.File;
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("path.separator");
        String libraryPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        for (String dir : libraryPath.split(lineSeparator)) {
            if (new File(dir + "/" + "pkcs11wrapper.dll").exists()) {
                System.out.println("found in: " + dir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**edit 2** the exception of the poster `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is not related to mixed DLL and JAR version, as this produces an `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

another try to get the error reason

**PKCS11Test.java**

```
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Info;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Slot;

public class PKCS11Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Module pkcs11Module = Module.getInstance(args[0]);
        pkcs11Module.initialize(null);
        pkcs11Module.finalize(null);
    }
}
```

**PKCS11Test.cmd**

```
set CLASS=PKCS11Test
set JAR=iaikPkcs11Wrapper.1.3.jar
set PKCS11_DLL=%~dp0\opensc_pkcs11.dll
rem cp PKCS11Wrapper.1.3.dll pkcs11wrapper.dll
javac -cp %JAR% %CLASS%.java || pause && exit
java -cp %JAR%;. -Djava.library.path=%~dp0 %CLASS% %PKCS11_DLL%
```

- replace the name of the DLL in the PKCS11_DLL variable with the name of your DLL
- the test expect all files in the same directory

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, 'pkcs11wrapper.dll' is the one that comes with pkcs#11 wrapper bundle. So, I am testing the compatible jar and dll versions and still get the same Exception.

Comment: @alikox Hi, I did some investigation it seems in your library path there is somewhere the DLL from version 1.2.17. see the **edit** section in my answer above.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, although it did find three of pkcs11 wrapper dll's all of them are in the same directory. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: When it's reported three times it means your PATH contains three times the directory `C:\Windows\system32\` (which is not a real problem).
What is the version of the DLL C:\Windows\system32\pkcs11wrapper.dll? The file size of the DLL version 1.3 is 99,328 bytes.

Comment: Hi, it is version 1.3 of the wrapper DLL.

Comment: Hi @alikox, maybe during your build comething get wrong as you get the exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` and in my tests I got `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. Have a look to the new **edit**

Comment: Hi, depending on the combination of the wrapper jar and native library versions, exception message changes from UnsatisfiedLinkError and NoSuchMethodError. I decided to go with the older version of the library. I upvote your answer so that you get half the bounty. Since the issue remains unresolved, I can not mark an answer as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related to your original question, but the suns bug [6880559](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6880559) and its duplicates indicate that there is some issue with pkcs11 implementation in Windows 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is one of the reasons I prefer IAIK's pkcs#11 provider over the one from Sun. Regards.